# How can i use the replace statement in query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to query a table that has values separated by commas as follows:

```
SELECT ID, NAME,FULLNAME,STATUS,STORE 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE STORE IN (SELECT '''' + REPLACE('001,002',',',''',''') +'''')
ORDER BY STORE
```

when I run the query above, it produces no results,
but when I run it like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME,FULLNAME,STATUS,STORE 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE STORE IN ('001','002')
ORDER BY STORE
```

I get like 500 records.

And when I try this:

```
SELECT ('''' + REPLACE('001,002',',',''',''') +'''')
```

I get the result '001','002'

so my question is, why the first script does not work, and produces no results?

Is there something I must add to the script for it to work?

please advise.

Comment: Let's back up a step. Why are you trying to build the string of `store` values like that? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Your design is problematic and will continue to cause you issues. Please stop treating SQL Server like a JSON utility. If you want to pass a set of values to check against, use a table-valued parameter. This string parsing nonsense is, well, nonsense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterize a SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

What if I had this scenario

```
SELECT ID, NAME,FULLNAME,STATUS,STORE 
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE 
WHERE STORE IN (
    SELECT t2.ID
    FROM (
        SELECT Value = REPLACE('001,002', ',', '.')
    ) t
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES 
            (PARSENAME(t.Value, 1)),
            (PARSENAME(t.Value, 2))
    ) t2 (ID)
)
AND STATUS IN (
    SELECT t2.ID1
    FROM (
        SELECT Value1 = REPLACE('A,T,L', ',', '.')
    ) t1
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES 
            (PARSENAME(t1.Value1, 1)),
            (PARSENAME(t1.Value1, 2))
    ) t2 (ID1)
)

ORDER BY STORE
```

I tried that, and it didn't work, so I am just wondering if it works for more than 1 condition.